# Copy elements at a given position in another position pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
num   mut
 67    O
 68    T
 69    D
   ...
```

I want to copy the second and third and so on element of the mut column into the first row, obtaining

```
num   mut
67    OTD...
68    T
69    D
  ...
```

How can I do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try

```py
df['mut'].iloc[0] = ''.join(df['mut'])
# or
df.loc[0, 'mut'] = ''.join(df['mut'])
```

```
print(df)

   num  mut
0   67  OTD
1   68    T
2   69    D
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to Ynjxsjmh. The difference is, instead of 2 & 3 row, you can make this code more dynamic.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [67, 68, 69],
                    'mut': ['O', 'T', 'D']})
```

You can use multiple row or different columns or also create a loop

```
x = df.iloc[1]['mut']
y = df.iloc[2]['mut']

val = ''.join([df.iloc[0]['mut'], x, y])
```

Update the relevant cell

```
df.iloc[0, 1] = val
print(df)
```